# How Can I set Localized Direction within application in hybrid mobile application using jquery

Tags: jquery, localization, globalization, right-to-left

we developing hybride application, this application have multi language support i.e english and arabic.

My Application must support Arabic(right to left direction) and English(left to right direction) language, I need to set UI and based on user select language from my application.

we using one html only for two language when user click on language option we are showing one html file only we just changing the labels using  NSL bundle so it can update labels automatically.

Now My Question is how can i achieve this? As My device language is say English and from my application user select Arabic(limited to my app only), So my Flow,UI,Animations etc should be right to left, using jquery we need and it is applicable all environments.

Please any one provide any sample application using jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can try to play with CSS *:lang* Selector http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_lang.asp and change from *direction:ltr* to *direction:rtl* something like:

```
    .text:lang(en) {
        direction: ltr;
    }
    .text:lang(rt) {
        direction: rtl;
    }
```

or change presentation view based on input locale also I recommend you store translation on thirty-part place/system like here http://l10n.ws for example